# G action on schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$ and $G$ a finite group such that $\mathrm{char}(k)$ does not devide the order of $G$. Then for some $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ one has $\mathrm{Ext}^i_G(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})=\mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})^G$. Does this equation holds for linearly reductive groups $G$ acting on $X$?